# How do you launch matlab from the linux terminal while also opening a matlab file?

Tags: linux, matlab

If I want to open file.m in the matlab editor, is there a way to do that directly from the linux  terminal?
I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: have you tried "`matlab file.m`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start matlab with the following command to open a file:

```
matlab -r 'edit <filename>'
```